# Propositional Formulas. Is my intuition regarding this problem correct?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

I've been having trouble with proving whether this propositional formula is true or false.

Let's say we the following propositional formulas: $(A \wedge B), (A \wedge C), (C \wedge B)$ where each of is satisfiable and each of A, B, C is a propositional formula.Does this mean that $((A \wedge B)\wedge C)$ is also satisfiable? Now just based on my intuition I would think that this should be true. I've tried to come up with any counter arguments but no avail. Would my intuition be right here?

Comment: Not very clear... but Yes, formula $((A∧B)∧C)$ is *satisfiable*. Try with the assignment $v(A)=v(B)=v(C)= \text T$

Comment: Just write out the truth table for the formula. If any of the rows evaluate to T, the formula is satisfiable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $A,B,C$ are propositional formulas, not necessarily just propositional variables.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say we the following propositional formulas: (A∧B),(A∧C),(C∧B)
> where each of is satisfiable and each of A, B, C is a propositional
> formula.

You don't mention whether they are simultaneously satisfiable, so I assume not. In that case, one can have $A\wedge B\wedge C$ not satisfiable: take propositional variables $p$ and $q$ and define
$$A=p, \quad B=q \quad\text{and}\quad C=\neg p\vee\neg q.$$
If $p$ is true, but $q$ is false, $A$ and $C$ are true and then $A\wedge C$ is satisfied. If $p$ and $q$ are true, $A$ and $B$ are true and $A\wedge B$ is satisfied. And if $q$ is true but $p$ is false, $B$ and $C$ are true, and $B\wedge C$ is satisfied.

But $A\wedge B\wedge C$ can not be satisfied: if $A$ and $B$ are true, $p$ and $q$ are true and therefore $C$ is false (obs.:the first example I cooked up had three variables and dozens of formulas, this one is much better!).

If, however, $A\wedge B$, $B\wedge C$ and $A\wedge C$ are simultaneously satisfiable, as Mauro ALLEGRANZA mentions in a comment, $A\wedge B\wedge C$ is satisfiable; actually, it is enough to assume any two among $A\wedge B$, $B\wedge C$ and $A\wedge C$ are simultaneously satisfiable.